# Generate compile_commands.json from msbuild via command line -- no cmake

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, clang-tidy

I'm looking for a way to integrate `clang-tidy` into a CI workflow, but the build system being used is MSBuild with dependencies managed by vcpkg in manisfest mode.

Is there some advanced command line that I can pass MSBuild (or some other tool that understands MSBuild process completely) to be able to generate `compile_commands.json`?

I'm sure I'm not the first one to try that, I've seen a couple of cases of success using `SourceTrail` and `ClangPowerTools`, but it has been specially painful in my case because the alternatives cannot detect the include paths exposed by vcpkg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that msbuild has a builtin target for clang-tidy since Visual Studio started to support that linter.

To invoke it one can run : `msbuild /t:ClangTidy ...`.

Unfortunately, very few command line options are exposed from the clang-tidy integration to msbuild CLI: the list of checks, the header-filter, additional compiler options, a flag for warnings in system headers and the tool path.

If one wants to export the fixes file generated by clang-tidy, which was my case, it needs to do some extra work.

I achieved my goal by adding one `Directory.Build.props` file in the project folder which overrides the path to the original `clang-tidy.exe` with a batch script (`.bat`), which does some preparation steps and forwards the msbuild target command line to a python script which can invoke clang-tidy with its full command line capabilities.

The props file:

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    
    <ClangTidyToolPath>$(where_I_saved_the_bat_file)\</ClangTidyToolPath>
    <ClangTidyToolExe>msbuild-clang-tidy-runner.bat</ClangTidyToolExe>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The batch file:

```
SET PYTHONPATH=...
REM and maybe other stuff
python3 -m my_custom_clang_tidy_runner  %*
```

Interestingly the batch file was the only way other than a real executable file that I could place in the `Directory.Build.props` that wouldn't result in msbuild compilation error. I tried python and powershell scripts and none were accepted as a suitable clang-tidy executable file. I experimented creating a C++ program which does the same as my Python script and it worked as expected as well.

So, to summarize, the recipe is:

1. Create the `Directory.Build.props` file in the root folder of the project you want to lint overriding the clang-tidy path.
2. A custom `.exe` or `.bat` file to replace clang-tidy capable of forwarding the command line options passed by msbuild together with any customisation you wish.
3. Invoke `msbuild /t:ClangTidy ...` and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: Hi @C.Nihelton could you share a demo project for this?

Answer (score 0):

## Yes!

You can run Clang-Cl, therefore you can use Clang's lesser-known **`-MJ` option**, which produces `compile_commands.json` for each file.

Combining that with `-fdriver-only` (to prevent compilation), a little bit of piping, and some string manipulation, you can join them all together.

#### tl;dr:

Run this from the Command Prompt (rename `MySolution.sln` to your solution file):

`@MSBuild -noLogo -v:d -t:ClCompile -m:1 -p:MultiProcMaxCount=1 -p:ContinueOnError=true -p:PlatformToolset=ClangCL "-p:ClangClAdditionalOptions=-fdriver-only -clang:-MJ-" MySolution.sln | powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "$include = ''; $outputs = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new(); ForEach ($line In @($input)) { If ($line.TrimStart().StartsWith('INCLUDE=')) { $include = $line.Substring($line.IndexOf('=') + 1); } ElseIf ($line.TrimStart() -Match '\"directory\":') { $json = $line.TrimEnd(',') | ConvertFrom-Json; $args = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new(); ForEach ($arg In $json.arguments) { If (($arg -ne '-clang:-MJ-') -and ($arg -ne '-fdriver-only')) { $args.Add($arg); } } ForEach ($dir In $include.Split([IO.Path]::PathSeparator)) { If ($dir.Length) { $args.Add('-imsvc'); $args.Add($dir); } } $json.arguments = $args.ToArray(); $outputs.Add('    ' + ($json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)); $include = ''; } }; '[' + [Environment]::NewLine + [string]::Join(',' + [Environment]::NewLine, $outputs.ToArray()) + [Environment]::NewLine + ']'"`

#### Warning

`compile_commands.json` doesn't include environment variables, which are necessary with MSVC for correct compilation.

The command above converts `INCLUDE=...` to `-imsvc ...` arguments, but if you want other environment variables converted somehow, you'll need to add handling for them.